# OneToOne mapping not working for abstract subclasses

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

I am having a frustrating mapping issue and definitely need some eyeballs.
I have an abstract class that has subclasses with an inheritance strategy of single table.
It holds a contact and that needs to also be an abstract class with the same inheritance strategy.
Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "leads")
@Cache(region = "com.qe.model.Lead", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public abstract class Lead {
    private Long id;
    protected Contact contact;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "lead")
    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "contacts")
@Cache(region = "com.qe.model.Contact", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public abstract class Contact {

    private Long id;
    private Lead lead;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lead_id")
    public Lead getLead() {
        return lead;
    }

    public void setLead(Lead lead) {
        this.lead = lead;
    }
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("AUTO")
public class AutoContact extends Contact {
}
```

I get an error of:

> Could not determine type for: com.qe.model.AutoContact, at table:
>   leads, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(contact)]

Any ideas would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, actually your mapping looks perfectly OK to me. The error message is puzzling me because obviously there shouldn't be a column `contact` in the `leads` table. Your mapping defines the foreign key column in the `contacts` table. Also polymorphic one-to-one associations should be supported by Hibernate.

You may try to add the `targetEntity` parameter to your mapping of `Contact` in class `Lead` (although I doubt that this will help).

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "lead", targetEntity = Contact.class)
public Contact getContact() {
  return contact;
}
```

You could also try to remove the `abstract` modifier from class `Contact` (although that may not be what you want to do).

Hope that helps.